# Generate HTML table header from multi dimensional array dynamically

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

My requirement is to generate HTML table header with Dynamic multi dimensional array.
e.g.
Array will be like,

```
$Array = ('Sr.No.'=>'',
'Subject'=>array('Maths','Sci','History','Social Sci')
'Other Activities'=>array('Sports','Computer','Social'));
```

HTML Header should have Sr. No. header with rowspan=2. Subject and Other activities to have colspan=4 and colspan=3 respectively. It will look like following,

[image]

Array is dynamic i.e.it is possible that there will be sub headers like, Sci can have physics and chemistry.

If you look at the table which have generated. There is Sci header in second row. It is possible that there is one more row which will show two section under Sci i.e. Physics and Chemistry. I mean this is a dynamic array which could have 3 or 4 levels. I need a script which will work for nth level. It could be 3, 4 etc. I hope my question is clear now.

I am able to show data with recursive function. But generating Header with colspan and rowspan dynamically is where I am stuck.

```
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th rowspan=2>Sr.No.<th>
     <th colspan=4>Subject</th>
     <th colspan=3>Other Activities</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <th>Maths</th>
     <th>Sci</th>
     <th>History</th>
     <th>Social Sci</th>
     <th>Sports</th>
     <th>Computer</th>
     <th>Social</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: You question and your exact problem is very unclear. Could you perhaps post the code you have tried so far? Also please make sure the question is not unnecessarily bloated with formatting and stick to the essentials so that it is readable.

Comment: Can you post an HTML example of what you want the end result to look like?

Comment: @RohitLondhe i have added an answer for you here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32218624/4323504

Comment: I have added an image with out put. Please take a look.

Comment: @RohitLondhe i updated my DEMO to fit your requirements, please check it below

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$headers = "<thead>";
foreach ($Array as $key => $value)
{
    $headers .= "<th colspan='".max(sizeOf($Array[$key]),1)."'>".$key."</th>";
}
$headers .= "</thead>";
```

Here is a working **[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cn%20$Array%20=%20array(%22Sr.No.%22%20=%3E%20%22%22,%5Cn'Subject'=%3Earray('Maths','Sci','History','Social%20Sci'),%5Cn'Other%20Activities'=%3Earray('Sports','Computer','Social'));%5Cn%5Cn%20$table%20=%20%22%3Ctable%20style='border-style:%20solid;'%3E%3Cthead%3E%22;%5Cn%20$headers%20=%20%22%3Ctr%3E%22;%5Cn%20$headers2%20=%20$headers;%5Cn%20foreach%20($Array%20as%20$key%20=%3E%20$value)%5Cn%20%7B%5Cn%20$headers%20.=%20%22%3Cth%20colspan='%22.max(sizeOf($Array[$key]),1).%22'%20style='border-right:%201px%20solid;'%3E%22.$key.%22%3C/th%3E%22;%5Cn%5Ct%20if(is_array($Array[$key]))%5Cn%5Ct%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%20foreach%20($Array[$key]%20as%20$key2%20=%3E%20$value2)%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%20$headers2%20.=%20%22%3Cth%20style='border:%201px%20dotted;'%3E%22.$value2.%22%3C/th%3E%22;%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%20%7D%5Cn%5Ct%20%7D%5Cn%5Ct%20else%7B$headers2%20.=%20%22%3Cth%20style='border:1px%20dotted;'%3E%3C/th%3E%22;%7D%5Cn%20%7D%5Cn$headers%20.=%20%22%3C/tr%3E%22;%5Cn$headers2%20.=%20%22%3C/tr%3E%22;%5Cn$table%20.=%20$headers.$headers2.%22%3C/thead%3E%3C/table%3E%22;%5Cn%5Cnecho%20$table;%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)**

**EDIT- BASED ON COMMENTS:**
The demo above have the following code:

```
$Array = array("Sr.No." => "",'Subject'=>array('Maths','Sci','History','Social Sci'),  
              'Other Activities'=>array('Sports','Computer','Social'));

$table = "<table style='border-style: solid;'><thead>";
$headers = "<tr>";
$headers2 = $headers;
foreach ($Array as $key => $value)
{
  $headers .= "<th colspan='".max(sizeOf($Array[$key]),1)."' style='border-right: 1px solid;'>".$key."</th>";
 if(is_array($Array[$key]))
 {
     foreach ($Array[$key] as $key2 => $value2)
     {
         $headers2 .= "<th style='border: 1px dotted;'>".$value2."</th>";
     }
 }
 else{$headers2 .= "<th style='border:1px dotted;'></th>";}
}
$headers .= "</tr>";
$headers2 .= "</tr>";
$table .= $headers.$headers2."</thead></table>";

echo $table;
```

**Here are the results:**

[image]

Comment: Demo is not working. Also I have tried code but it is generating only first row i.e. Sr.No., Subject, Other Activities. It is not generating the second row.

Comment: @RohitLondhe what do you mean  demo not working, all you have to do is click the link, and click run on the demo, anyway i will edit this answer with the code on the demo

Comment: Thanks for Solution Luthando. But as mentioned in the question this array is dynamic i.e.it is possible that there will be sub headers like Sci can have physics and chemistry. The solution you have given will work for two levels but not for n level

Comment: If you look at the table which have generated by you. There is Sci header in second row. It is possible that there is one more row which will show two section under Sci i.e. Physics and Chemistry. I mean this is a dynamic array which could have 3 or 4 levels. I need a script which will work for nth level. It could be 3, 4 etc. I hope my question is clear now.