# PHP Irregular Multi Level Header

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops

I'm new to web programming i need your help to solve mine.
I tried to search every problem in Stackoverflow but i haven't encountered something similar to my case.
It's about creating an irregular header in html with PHP.

I've encountered problem about creating irregular multi-level header using PHP.
I tried few tricks myself but it remain unsolved.

My PHP array :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php 
$multi_header = array(
                  array('id'=>0,
      'name'=>'Working',
      'level_1'=>'Economically Active',
      'level_3'=>NULL,
      'group'=>'Employment'
      ),
                  array('id'=>1,
      'name'=>'Ever Worked',
      'level_1'=>'Unemployment',
      'level_3'=>'Economically Active',
      'group'=>'Employment'
      ),
                  array('id'=>2,
      'name'=>'Never Worked',
      'level_1'=>'Unemployment',
      'level_3'=>'Economically Active',
      'group'=>'Employment'
      ),
                  array('id'=>3,
      'name'=>'Total',
      'level_1'=>'Unemployment',
      'level_3'=>'Economically Active',
      'group'=>'Employment'
      ),
                  array('id'=>4,
      'name'=>'Total of Economically Active',
      'level_1'=>'Economically Active',
      'level_3'=>NULL,
      'group'=>'Employment'
      ),
                  array('id'=>5,
      'name'=>'Percentage of Working to Economically Active',
      'level_1'=>NULL,
      'level_3'=>NULL,
      'group'=>'Employment'
      ),
                  array('id'=>6,
      'name'=>'Attending School',
      'level_1'=>'Not Economically Active',
      'level_3'=>NULL,
      'group'=>'Employment'
      ),
                  array('id'=>7,
      'name'=>'Housekeeping',
      'level_1'=>'Not Economically Active',
      'level_3'=>NULL,
      'group'=>'Employment'
      ),
                  array('id'=>8,
      'name'=>'Others',
      'level_1'=>'Not Economically Active',
      'level_3'=>NULL,
      'group'=>'Employment'
      ),
                  array('id'=>9,
      'name'=>'Total of Not Economically Active',
      'level_1'=>'Not Economically Active',
      'level_3'=>NULL,
      'group'=>'Employment'
      ),
                  array('id'=>10,
      'name'=>'Total',
      'level_1'=>NULL,
      'level_3'=>NULL,
      'group'=>'Employment'
      ),
                  array('id'=>11,
      'name'=>'Percentage of Economically Active to Working Age Population',
      'level_1'=>NULL,
      'level_3'=>NULL,
      'group'=>'Employment'
      )
                );

?>
```

I need to create table header like this
[My Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W4ow.png)

I want them to look like this :

```html
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}


</style>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan='3'>Scope/Coverage</td>
   <td colspan='5'>Economically Active</td>
   <td rowspan='3'>Percentage of Working to Economically Active</td>
   <td colspan='4'>Not Economically Active</td>
   <td rowspan='3'>Total</td>
   <td rowspan='3'>Percentage of Economically Active to Working Age Population</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan='2'>Working</td>
   <td colspan='3'>Unemployment</td>
   <td rowspan='2'>Total of Economically Active</td>
   <td rowspan='2'>Attending School</td>
   <td rowspan='2'>Housekeeping</td>
   <td rowspan='2'>Total of Not Economically Active</td>
   
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Ever Worked</td>
   <td>Never Worked</td>
   <td>Total</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 
</table>
```

What should i do?
I need to look like that.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to iterate over the array, optionally [using the alternative syntax][1] to render the item as an html table. Or use a template engine: [Simple PHP template engine](https://github.com/ddycai/simple-template-engine) or [the famous Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/)

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218553/generate-html-table-header-from-multi-dimensional-array-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Welcome.  So, there are a number of ways it can be achieved.  First, remember, that it is probably better to express what you are trying to do as HTML only, however, if you must use PHP here is one possible way.

```
$tableHeader = '[
    {
        "title": "Scope/Coverage",
        "type":  "rowspan",
        "span":  3
    },
    {
        "title": "Economically Active",
        "type":  "colspan",
        "span":  3
    }
]';

foreach (json_decode($tableHeader) as $row) {
  echo "<tr {$row->type}=\"{$row->span}\">{$row->title}</tr>\r\n";
}
```

You will of course need to add the rest of your table headings but you get the picture.  You could store your JSON for your table separately in some config in case you needed to modify it in the future.

Comment: Well i was only allowed to use $multi_header array.
Should i convert it into json?

Comment: You can easily use multidimensional array with similar syntax